# Checking if input is an integer in C

Tags: c, debugging

I'm trying to check if a number is an integer (num).

In the main() -

```
int num, input;
    printf("Please enter an integer greater than 1:\n");
        input = scanf("%d",&num);
        if ( input != 1 ){
            printf("Invalid input!\n");
            return 1;
        }
```

but when the input is not an integer (33.3 for example), the value of "input" is still 1.

```
printf("%d ", input);
```

gives me back 1.

The rest of the program works. Just got stuck on this minor thing.

Comment: 33.3 will be read as integer 33.

Comment: The return of `scanf` will tell you if it succeeded or not

Comment: I don't seem you have done your searches on google before posting this on stackoverflow...Please do some background before asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need to read the input into a `char[]`, (so, no `scanf()` necessary, you can just do `gets()` or something similar,) and then check the value yourself, digit by digit, using `isdigit()`.